# HTML CSS Form - How to center the form on the page?

Tags: html, css, forms, margin

I made a form and I am trying to center it on page but it doesn't work. I tried applying these 2 CSS to it but it didn't work.

```
form{margin: 0 auto;}

form{margin: auto;}
```

I also tried enclosing the form into div.container and applying same CSS to it but still nothing.

But this works:

```
{margin: 0 250px 0;}
```

Form [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bMf9M/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need  to do two things to achieve this:

1) Change `inline-block` display on the form to be `block`. 
2) Fix the width (you currently have it as `auto`).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bMf9M/2/

Or if you don't want to fix the form size, you can use `text-align: center` (Thanks @donderpiet)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bMf9M/4/

Comment: But what if you want the form to auto-adjust its width? It's easier to leave the `inline-block` and add `text-align: center` to its parent.

Comment: Doesn't width: auto sets width to minimum width required?

Comment: @donderpiet Then you'd end up with **all** the form centered, like so http://jsfiddle.net/bMf9M/5/

Comment: @SourabhVerma It does, but it's not fixed and in order to center it, you'll need to fix the width.

Comment: You have to set `text-align: left` on the form, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/bMf9M/4/

Comment: One solution that I found myself: in form `display: table;`.and everyting works well.

Comment: @SourabhVerma Depends on your audience, `display: table` won't work in IE7 and below, IE8 requires a DocType

Comment: @SourabhVerma Using the method in my edit means that you don't have to fix the form size (thanks donderpiet)

Comment: Ok I'll use `text-align: center;` in `body` and `text-align: left;` in `form` (See, this is why people hate IE). Thanks for your help mattytommo and donderpiet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the width of the container as elements with `display:block` property automatically size to the maximum width of their container.

Comment: What if you want your container to auto adjust its width>?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a Width if you like to use margin:auto;

Comment: Not on elements that have a `display: inline-block;` property.

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` has a property `display: inline-block;`, which makes it behave like an inline element. So you have to add `text-align: center;` to its parent to make it center horizontally. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bMf9M/4/.

Don't forget to set the form's `text-align` to `left`, otherwise it will have center-aligned text.

Comment: It also centers the text inside to I have to reset it to text-align: left;
is there any better way?

Comment: I don't think so, not while using the `inline-block` value.